# Looking for a Variation of multi-armed Archemides Spiral

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm looking for any type of equation(s) or algorithm(s) that can be used to describe a variation of the multi-armed Archimedes Spiral.
 
In a true archimedes spiral, the gap between one arm and the next is a constant radial distance, but especially as the number of arms, n, gets larger, the perpendicular distance between the arms reduces towards zero as the spiral arms come in steeply to the center.

[image: This image shows an Archimedes spiral with 20 arms. Notice how the gaps between arms get thinner at the center]

I'm looking for a slightly different spiral in which the distance between one arm and the next will always be a constant perpendicular distance, better modeling a true constant-thickness media such as a rug or a rope, all the way down to some minimal starting radius near the origin.

One general equation for an n-armed Archimedes spiral is:
$$R(\theta) = \frac{na}{2\pi}\theta+ka$$
where n is the number of arms in the spiral, a is the radial distance between arms, and k is an index counter that goes from 0 to n-1, for generating each of the n arms.

Given the same variables n and a, but changing the definition of a to be the local perpendicular distance between arms rather than the radial distance, I’d like to find:

• Any type of equation(s) or iterative computer algorithms(s) that will precisely describe the spiral arcs,

• The minimum diameter circle which will reside at the center of all of the spiral arcs.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: This problem can be asked with 25% of the words, and would get more attention.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to edit it into fewer words, but when I do so a "How to Edit" box pops up, making it very difficult to see what I'm doing. Is there a way to keep that box from popping up, or dismiss it when it does? I'm not seeing anything to click to do so.

Comment: @Danby You want constant normal thickness, right?

Comment: It's hard to keep focus on your post.

Comment: In response to David & Croissant, I've done my best to make the problem statement brief and to the point. The "How to Edit" box makes things so much more difficult to edit things, as it hides what I'm trying to edit. Is there no way to get this out of the way? Or is there some browser where it will be to the side, and not in the way? I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot successfully tailor an Archimedean Spiral to maintain constant rug thickness normally.You should look for the proper spiral with that property.

An [Involute of a Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute#Involutes_of_a_circle) keeps the normal separation constant. It should  start with a *Base Circle*, (magenta) below which the rugs cannot be rolled without interference.

A division of Base Circle segment equals the normal distance, as seen in the sketch.

A single involute has parametric equation with $\theta$ parameter
$$ x = a \sqrt{1+\theta^2} \cos(\theta -tan^{-1}\theta),
y = a \sqrt{1+\theta^2} \sin(\theta -tan^{-1}\theta); $$

And include other $n$ arms by matrix rotation $ \pi/n$,

[image: Involute]

Comment: Thank you!! I never knew this aspect of involutes of a circle.

Comment: However, it doesn't look like it would be possible with these curves to go all the way around the circle with them, since already in the image you've shown, each of the involutes going leftward is smaller than the one to its right. 
I'm looking for a way to fill the entire area around the base circle with spirals of some kind.
I'd still expect it would be possible to do this, and I'd also expect that it would meet the base circle at some angle, not at 90 degrees.

Comment: All are of the same size and length.  Please look carefully only at at normal direction width, do not look at circumferential widths. Ignore the tapering part at outer boundary edge.

Comment: You are correct - I'm very happy to be wrong about this!

Comment: fine, It is through error corrections that we learn.

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance, Narasimham!

Comment: Welcome, happy to be of some help. btw, next find the polar equation, guarding that $\theta$ is not polar angle.